# Expo Stuck on Splash Screen

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg

I recently my expo version and my app will now no longer work. I've even tried reverting my app's codebase to a previous commit before I made the changes to my packages. I don't get any errors, instead the app "boots" up and is stuck on the default expo splash screen.

update: Minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/atb-brown/expo-issue

update: A freshly initiated app seems to work: https://github.com/atb-brown/expo-issue/tree/expo-init

```
$ expo --version
5.0.3
```

```json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "ansi-regex": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.4.6",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "node-notifier": "^10.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-44.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.4",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^44.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "yarn-audit-fix": "^9.0.10"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The Expo Go app on my android is version 2.23.2.

This is the screen that my app gets stuck on:

[image: Expo App Stuck on this screen]

There are no errors in the console that I can see. What could possibly be going wrong here?

Comment: try out these suggestions from this troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/splash-screen-hanging.md

Comment: Hmm. Nothing there seemed to be helpful to me. I'm never calling that `SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()` and then I've already tried the tips there on the manual debugging guide. I did create a minimal reproducible example, though, which I'll link in the original post with an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the issue in my case was that I was resolving the `uuid` package.

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
```

Removing `uuid` from my resolutions fixed my issue, although I still don't know precisely what was going wrong, but clearly Expo needed something from a different version of a uuid package.

Answer (score 1):

Similar kind of issue occurred for me. The reason for the issue was I missed giving 'return' keyword inside the component.

```
const App = () => {

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
      <Text style={{ margin: 20 }}>Scroll here to see more!</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```